# Twitter Bootstrap issue with IE11 when set with Browser Profile Enterprise

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I'm stuck with a issue with a web page built with Bootstrap 3. The company IE is configured to load intranet pages in Enterprise profile mode in some machines. For others users the default profile set in IE11 is Desktop.

[image]

With this configuration the layout broke completely.

But when I changed to another profile like desktop the web page works normally if any kind of document mode (Edge, IE10, 9, 8 also 7).

Also I'm using conditional style control to fix some layout problems and with IE 8 polyfills also respond and html5shiv libraries.

[image]

[image]

[image]

***There is a way to detect if IE11 is in the Enterprise profile using html5, js or CSS3? How user agent IE emulates in this profile?***

Someone has found layout trouble with modern HTML5/Bootstrap web sites intranet or IE11 in Enterprise mode?

I'm guessing that isn't possible to turn this mode off in my company.

Thanks for help.

Comment: FYI Enterprise mode is "IE8 mode", basically it runs IE8 instead of IE11. Bootstrap 3 should still support it, albeit in greatly reduced visuals: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9

Comment: I suggest you develop your site in IE8 to make sure it runs Enterprise Mode and do not use any modern browsers

Comment: I know that  Enterprise profile IE11 behavior like IE8, but when I test in IE8 or emulate IE8 using Desktop profile the layout works fine. This is the issue.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28821906/315168

Answer (score 0):

`.right:{<style><div></div></style>}` (yes/no).

`.Right{color: #fffff ; background: #dvsdsadga; }` (yes/no).

`<button>Share  public yes/no touch this button</button>`

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)