# Detect if IE11 is in the Enterprise profile using html5, CSS3 or JS

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer

I need to know the user agent of IE 11 in the browser profile set enterprise when people use a specific web page in the intranet.

I'm having trouble with layout and I'm using twitter boostrap

It's possible to accomplish this using html5/js or css?

Someone knows some libraries to help with these needs?

Thanks for help.

Comment: ... why? It sounds like you're asking for a way to find out IE11's page mode in order to "do something different". So instead of asking about detecting the mode, can you explain what you're trying to *do* that makes you ask about IE11's mode? Let's try to prevent [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why the duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171822/twitter-bootstrap-issue-with-ie11-when-set-with-browser-profile-enterprise

Comment: Not duplicate, this question is more specific and I asking different thinks